# Static Sitemap.xml Django

Tags: python, xml, django, sitemap

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to add a basic sitemap.xml. I only have static pages. How do I add a simple sitemap.xml so that I can access it from http://mydomain.com/sitemap.xml

```
urls.py
pages 
  --- templates
        ---- pages
                -- about.html
                -- contact.html
                -- etc...
  --- views.py
```

In my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from [myfolder].pages.views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',        TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/home.html'), name='home'),
    url(r'^about/$',     TemplateView.as_view(template_name='about.html')),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml/$',     TemplateView.as_view(template_name='sitemap.xml')),????
)
```

How can I generate a sitemap based off the pages I have in templates/pages??

Comment: Have you seen this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#example

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#sitemap-for-static-views

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to the previous answers is to do a similar thing to adding the `robots.txt` file to your `urls.py` file.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='sitemap.xml', content_type='text/xml')),
)
```

The only difference is to change the `content_type` value to `text/xml` where it would be `text/plain` for the `robots.txt` file

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Django-static-sitemap
It actually generates the XML file.
https://github.com/xaralis/django-static-sitemaps